# Save a list of interface items in a SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm developing an app at the moment. To save the items I want to use an SQLite database. The implementation works in general (using the [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) library), however I'm failing at saving a collection of items that inherit from a interface called `IItem`.

It works the following way:

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), "myapp.db");

// Code that creates the `items` list.

foreach (IItem item in items)
    conn.InsertOrReplace(item, typeof(IItem));
```

But to reduce the overhead, I prefer it to do it this way:

```
conn.InsertOrReplaceAll(items, typeof(List<IItem>));
```

Sadly this doesn't work due to an `System.Reflection.TargetException`.

Any ideas to get the latter one working, primary because of perf reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using wrong type as the parameter in `InsertOrReplaceAll` method. The `objType` in this method represents the **type of the single item**, you can use this method like following:

```
conn.InsertOrReplaceAll(items, typeof(IItem));
```

To see this clearly, we can look at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net/SQLiteConnection.cs#L1442):

```
public int InsertOrReplaceAll(IEnumerable objects, Type objType)
{
    var c = 0;
    RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        foreach (var r in objects)
        {
            c += InsertOrReplace(r, objType);
        }
    });
    return c;
}
```

From the source code, we can find in this method, it also calls `InsertOrReplace(object obj, Type objType)` method. Besides, there is another overload method of `InsertOrReplaceAll`.

```
public int InsertOrReplaceAll(IEnumerable objects);
```

With this method, we can do not care about the type issue.